# What is the Physics Behind Invisibility of Writing with any color over Black color

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

If I Write something with a black pen on a piece of paper and try to scribble something with say, a red pen over it, Why can't I view it as a separate entity from the black ink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you can see the scribbles or not, depends on the kind of ink the pen uses. Most regular inks will absorb all wavelenghts except the ones corresponding to the color they should be; e.g. a red pen will absorb everything except red light. For these kinds of inks, it matters what they are painted on, because the light passes through them, onto the surface they are applied to, gets reflected there, and passes back through the ink.

If the surface they are painted on does not reflect light (like black paper, or paper you painted black with another pen), red light passes through the ink, but gets absorbed by the black layer underneath. There is no reflected light you can see.

Some types of ink work in a different way. They directly reflect only the wavelength corresponding to their color, and absorb the others. Such ink will be visible even on black objects. This is similar to how chalk is visible on a blackboard.